dplyr::select or dplyr::filter - if all values are TRUE
I have this kind of dataframe, but with a total of 14294 Gene_IDs and 36 Exp columns.
Gene_ID Exp_A   Exp_B   Exp_C    Exp_D
Gene1   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE    FALSE
Gene2   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE    TRUE
Gene3   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE    FALSE
Gene4   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE    TRUE
Gene5   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE    FALSE

I am attempting to filter the rows according to the number of TRUE. I am interested in Gene_IDs where all but one value is TRUE, or only three values are TRUE, etc.
I have tried using filter. I also have tried transposing the data frame, where each column is a Gene_ID, and tried to select.
Nothing really works. I also got some errors. For example:
df %>% filter(if_any(everything(), ~ .x == TRUE))

gives me an
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart

Is there any dplyr function which is the best to do this?

There might be better ways to do it but I don't think that code should generate that error on a binary data frame of that size. It would be best if you update your question with a minimal reproducible example, perhaps using sample() and set.seed(), to create a data frame that allows others to reproduce your issue.

We do not need much for that; base: df0[rowSums(df0[startsWith(names(df0), "Exp")])==3, ], where df0 is your data.

Assuming you do have a data.frame with logical Exp_ columns, you could use pick() for subsetting and rowSums() for counting:
library(dplyr)

read.table(header = TRUE, text = 
"Gene_ID Exp_A   Exp_B   Exp_C    Exp_D
Gene1   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE    FALSE
Gene2   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE    TRUE
Gene3   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE    FALSE
Gene4   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE    TRUE
Gene5   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE    FALSE") |> 
  filter(rowSums(pick(starts_with("Exp")) == TRUE) == 3)
#>   Gene_ID Exp_A Exp_B Exp_C Exp_D
#> 1   Gene2  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

Created on 2024-11-11 with reprex v2.1.1

Do we really need == TRUE? Looks a bit odd to me. Haven't checked.

Good point, not really needed. Though for some other variations like  "all but one value is TRUE" I'd personally prefer (to read) filter(rowSums(pick(starts_with("Exp")) == FALSE) == 1) instead of something like  filter(rowSums(!pick(starts_with("Exp"))) == 1)
